# Form Abandonment data google tag manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

For Form Abandonment tracking in Google Tag Manager. Below is the code (original code from http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-abandonment-with-google-tag-manager/). I have modified the code as per my requirement.

```
    (function() {
    var formSelector = '.webform-component-fieldset';
    var attribute = 'name';
    var history = [];
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
        if (history.length) {
            var x = history.join(' > ');
            var x= x.replace(/submitted[fieldset_user_info]/g,"");
            window.dataLayer.push({
                'event' : 'formAbandonment',
                'category' : 'Form Abandonment',
                'action' : x

            });
        };
    });
});

 document.querySelector(formSelector).addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    history.push(e['target'].getAttribute(attribute));
});
})();
```

The code is getting executed but the output is not desired one.
The output I am getting for eventAction datalayer ( 'action': x) is as below

> submitted[fieldset_user_info][first_name] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][street_address_1] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][street_address_2] > 
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][city] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][state] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][zip_code] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info] [e_mail_address] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][confirm_e_mail_address] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][last_name] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info] [street_address_2] >
>   submitted[fieldset_user_info][i_prefer_to_receive_communications_from_pfizer_by]

I want to remove every occurrence of the text "submitted[fieldset_user_info]" from output but with above code I am not able to do

Can any help with modification to code needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace string

```
var x= x.replace(/submitted[fieldset_user_info]/g,"");
```

by string:

`var x= x.replace("submitted[fieldset_user_info]","");`

According to the [description of JS replace() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) it supports both regular expressions as well as string as the 1st parameter.

I tried to test "replace()" method in the console with two variations: with your RegEx and with the simple string: method succesfully working only with the string. May be something is wrong in your regEx(by me it looks correct).

Comment: Hi  Buttersmai Thanks for the help . I have done the changes as per the suggestion ,but the problem is that it is only replacing first "submitted[fieldset_user_info]" with "" rest of the "submitted[fieldset_user_info]" visible. I want to remove all the "submitted[fieldset_user_info]" on the report

Comment: just added \ before special character [ and  it worked for me